# Codeigniter, I used active record to update my data in my database and I want it to redirect back to my Edit Page showing the updated data

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I used active record to update my data in my database and its updated inside the database, but after updating data inside the database, I want it to redirect back to my Edit Page showing the updated data from my database.. but what I have tried is not working.

my codeigniter version is 2.7

```html
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class account extends CI_Controller {
function __construct()
 {
 parent::__construct();
  
  }
 
public function index(){
 
 $username = $this->input->post('username');
 $password = $this->input->post('password');
 $result = $this->login_model->database($username, $password);
 if ($result == TRUE){
 $data['posts'] = $result;
 $data['subview'] = 'testview';
  $this->load->view('display', $data);
 }else{
 echo "invalid password";
 };
}

public function edit(){
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $name = $this->input->post('name');
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $telephone = $this->input->po

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

st('telephone');
        $result = $this->login_model->update($id, $name, $email, $telephone);

```
    $data['posts'] = $result;
    $data['message'] =   "Record Updated Successfully."; // Print this Message in your edit view page as echo $message.
        $data['subview'] = 'testview';
        $this->load->view('display', $data);
    }

}
```

```
  <!--THIS IS MY MODEL-->
```

```html
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class login_model extends CI_Model {
function __construct()
 {
 parent::__construct();
  
  }
 
 public function database($username, $password)
 { 
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('user');
  $this->db->where('username', $username);
  $this->db->where('password', $password);
  $this->db->limit(1);
  $query = $this->db->get();
  if($query->num_rows() ==1){
   return $query->result();
   }else{
   return false;
   }
 }
 
 public function update($id){
 $data = array(
               'id' => $this->input->post('id'),
               'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
               'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
               'telephone' => $this->input->post('telephone'),
            );

$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->update('user', $data); 
}

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

```
Please update your model's update fuction like the following code.

public function update()
{
    $id =   $this->input->post('id');
    $name   =   $this->input->post('name');
    $email  =   $this->input->post('email');
    $telephone  =   $this->input->post('telephone');

    $data = array(
               'name' => $name,
               'email' => $email,
               'telephone' => $telephone,
            );
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('user', $data); 
}

Create a new function in your model for fetch the record with same updated id like the following

public function view($id)
{
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $result =   $this->db->get('user');
        return $result->result();
}


Please update your controller's edit Function like the following

public function edit(){

    $id =   $this->input->post('id');
    $result = $this->login_model->update();

    if ($result)
    {
       $resultData  =   $htis->login_model->view($id);//Calling the newly create model function for tething the record.
       $data_arr['id']  =   $id;
       $data_arr['name']    =   $resultData[0]->name;
       $data_arr['email']   =   $resultData[0]->email;
       $data_arr['telephone']   =   $resultData[0]->telephone;
       $this->load->view('edit', $data_arr);//Loading the edit view
    }
}


Assume, your edit view is as follows, just I am creating a view with neccessary fiels only

View Name:  edit.php //Saved in to view folder.

<form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('account/edit');?>"> <!--account is the controller and edit is the controller's function-->
<input type="text" name="id" value="<?php if(isset($id)){ php echo $id;}?>">
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php if(isset($name)){ php echo $name;}?>">
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php if(isset($email)){ php echo $email;}?>">
<input type="text" name="telephone" value="<?php if(isset($telephone)){ php echo $telephone;}?>">
<input type="submit" value="Edit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for your contribution, but i cant still view the data from the database.. i will upload my view for you to see and adjustment have made to the code

Comment: Please share your code I will try to provide you the best solution.